# 403 in Response to OPTIONS when updating working copy having full access

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, http-status-code-403

There is an SVN repository (single repository) http://example.net/svn

The repository contains several projects (directories):

```
http://example.net/svn/Project1
http://example.net/svn/Project2
```

User has full access to Project1 directory and has no access neither to root nor to Project2.

Everything works fine for a while: user checks out `http://example.net/svn/Project1`, commits and updates it successfully.

But sometimes trying to update leads to the following error:

> Command: Update
>   Error: Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to OPTIONS
>   Error: request for 'http://example.net/svn'
>   Finished!

**Why does TortoiseSVN request something in the root???**

I have noticed that this happens after somebody else committed copy or move operation. Checking out `http://example.net/svn/Project1` helps till next time...

The main question: **How to set up access rights for user to avoid these errors?** Note, it's not an option to grant user any read or write access right on the root directory for security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Subversion 1.5: [Issue 3242](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3242).  Some move operations were setting revision properties on parents that were unnecessary.

Have you tried upgrading your SVN server?

I hope this helps.

Thank you,
Zachary

Comment: This was the cause indeed. Upgrading server helped. Thanks.